# AWS S3 vs AWS Global Infrastructure: Availability Zones mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There's a statement in AWS S3 documentation that objects in S3 are replicated and stored across at least three geographically-dispersed Availability Zones. However, on the [Global Infrastructure page](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/) there are a few regions (Canada Central and Beijing) with only 2 Availability Zones available.

If I understand it right, the replication settings are region-specific and all objects will be replicated only across 2 Availability Zones. Does anybody have any insights on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some regions have fewer than three availability zones *accessible to customers*, but none -- apparently -- have fewer than three where S3 is deployed.

> Amazon S3 Standard, S3 Standard-Infrequent Access, and S3 Glacier storage classes replicate data across a minimum of three AZs to protect against the loss of one entire AZ. This remains true in Regions where fewer than three AZs are publicly available.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

Comment: Do you mean that there are at least 3 AZ in Canada Central but only 2 of them are publically available?

Comment: That's correct -- there's at least one hidden AZ that you can't see in your AWS account.